# How do I change the padding of an image at a specific screen width?

Tags: image, padding, point

I'm building a site that's 1450px width.

There's a logo that's flushed right of the 1450px max-width at the top of the site, followed by a 1450px-width image underneath.

I want to keep it this way, but when resizing the screen for tablet or mobile, the logo remains flushed all the way to the right.

I want to add about 20px padding to the right of the logo, so it's not flushed to the edge on mobile and tablet screens, but make it aligned with the 1450px image (and flushed to edge of image) for desktop screens.

How do I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help.

Here's the code I used and it works now. (I needed margin, not padding, btw, because the padding was actually squishing the width of the image).

```
img.logo
    {
width: 200px; 
float: right; 
padding-top: 20px; 
padding-bottom: 20px;
    } 


@media all and (max-width: 1450px) {
img.logo
    {
margin-right:20px;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code below:

```
<style>
  @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) { ... }
</style>
```

This will apply the css in the { ... } to devices that have a screen width of a maximum of 800x.

You could set `.logo padding-right:20px;` and it will only apply to smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use media query view port in css

in CSS you need these tags

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
Inside here you add what you want changed for this screen
}
```

EG:

```
a {
 padding: 20px;  // Original
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  a {
    padding: 10px; // only applies to screens up to 480 px view port
   }
```

Best of luck do some more research there is lot on this Google for " Responsive Design "

Addition:

You can have as many view-ports or SCREENS in one CSS as you want, so you can change properties on any size you need. :)